# MERN - TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'username' of 'req.body' as it is undefined

Tags: node.js, express, authentication, passport.js

I am trying to authenticate an user, I'm building the backend first and testing it on Insomnia, when I send the request an error saying `TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'username' of 'req.body' as it is undefined.` happens.

I'm using passportjs and jwt.

This is my "server.js" file: https://www.paste.org/110929

This is my code for the "/users/signin" route: https://www.paste.org/110930

My passport.js file: https://www.paste.org/110931

I would be extremely grateful of any help as this issue has got me stuck for a good while

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add `body-parser` to your server.js file to catch the request body

```
const express = require('express')
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
 
const app = express()
 
// parse application/x-www-form-urlencoded
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }))
 
// parse application/json
app.use(bodyParser.json())
```

**UPDATE**

Since express 4.16.0, you can also do:

```
const express = require('express')
 
const app = express()

// parse application/x-www-form-urlencoded
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }))
     
// parse application/json
app.use(express.json())
```

Comment: Fixed it! I was missing the 'status' in res.json({ success: true, token "Bearer" + token })

Comment: I think right new recommended approach is to use `app.use(express.json())`

Comment: @p__d Thank you yes I was planning to update the answer. and I just did it